# show category and item in joomla 1.5 weblink

Tags: joomla

If I want to edit a link to a Web component to be displayed.

joomla standard weblink :

```
category A(num)
category B(num)
category C(num)
```

Customize weblink :

```
category A
[*]link 1 in child cat A
[*]link 2 in child cat A
[*]link etc..

category B
[*]link 1 in child cat B
[*]link 2 in child cat B
[*]link etc..

category C
[*]link 1 in child cat C
[*]link 2 in child cat C
[*]link etc..
```

tanx

Answer (score 0):

This is not a programming question but use the categorIES layout and play around with the options about what categories to display.

Comment: Hi
Thanks for the answer
There is no such option in Joomla.
Joomla code requires a little editing.

Thank you

Comment: Yup you really need to update since 1.5 is EOL plus you will get lots of better options.